# how to create Vertical align android button in xml..?

Tags: android, android-button

how to make vertical align button android in android XML file like the image [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use android:background and put a picture like this button in the drawables you will can make it for example:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_button"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use fill_parent for layout_height. For OK you can make it K below O, but like on the picture must use background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can make height more and width less that ways the size of button will come up the way you want and for the "ok" thing, you will have to create it as the background image.